# How does AngularJS update the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Specifically, I'm wondering how they update elements without using innerHTML. In the docs, they clearly state how they're better than other templating engines because they [don't re-render with innerHTML](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) (ctrl-f innerHTML -- sorry). I started poking through the source code but there's a LOT of it and was hoping that perhaps I could get a faster answer from you guys.

So far my guesses have been

- The compiler converts `{{test}}` into something like `<ng-bind>test</ng-bind>` which the linker can update when data changes, but it doesn't seem like this is happening when I look at the DOM of a rendered Angular page. And also seems like it could interfere with a client's CSS and other javascript components external to Angular.
- They actually are using innerHTML but they're just not re-rendering the ENTIRE DOM -- only a small snippet of it (perhaps the data inside some sort of custom `<ng-bind></ng-bind>` tag).
- They're somehow removing and appending new elements ... bad guess I think.

If anyone knows I'd love to learn. Otherwise it's back to the source code for me.

---

**EDIT** New Guess

After thinking about it some more, I believe this might be what happens: Compiler swallows html, say something like

```
<p> 
  {{model}} 
  <div> 
    <p> Hello ! </p> 
  </div> 
</p>
```

And converts it to this:

```
<p class="ng-binding"> 
  {{model}} 
  <div> 
    <p> Hello ! </p> 
  </div> 
</p>
```

Then Angular can crawl through and index all angular text nodes ( `{{model}}` ) `eg document.getElementsByClass('ng-binding')[0].childNodes[0]`. Each stored node can then be associated by the linker with a scoped model `$scope['model']`. Each node can then be updated extremely quickly by setting `node.nodeValue = $scope['somemodel`] (simplified)` and voilà, technically no innerHTML'ing and lightning speed DOM updates.

Comment: I highly recommend [How do I think in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/) in the Related links on the right.

Comment: @StephenP Whew! lots of good stuff there, thanks! Out of curiosity, I spent my weekend reimplementing some features of Angular -- I know I know, why reinvent a perfectly round wheel -- and I was particularly curious about the nitty gritty internals of this one.

Comment: @vin, do you have your work posted anywhere? I'm trying to build a better understanding of the "how" in Angular, especially how it updates the dom.  Would greatly appreciate learning from your code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than replacing the element itself, as `innerHTML` would do, Angular prefers to modify the properties of existing elements.

The `ng-bind` directive is actually a good example. It keeps a reference to the `element` and just updates its `.text()` as the `$scope` changes ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.1.5/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L50-L55)):

```
var ngBindDirective = ngDirective(function(scope, element, attr) {
  element.addClass('ng-binding').data('$binding', attr.ngBind);
  scope.$watch(attr.ngBind, function ngBindWatchAction(value) {
    element.text(value == undefined ? '' : value);
  });
});
```

This doesn't necessarily mean Angular won't use `innerHTML` at times, especially when creating new content. But, it tries to avoid it when possible.